# pygame does not detect events from virtual uinput device (Ubuntu Jammy)

Tags: python, linux, pygame, joystick, uinput

I am currently working on the PR that ports `vgamepad` to Linux. `vgamepad` emulates virtual gamepads in python.
On Linux, the PR uses `libevdev` which in turns creates a `uinput` device.
In order to check consistency of the library across platforms, I am trying to use `pygame` for checking the state of `vgamepad`'s virtual gamepads.
The code for these unit tests is available [here](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad/blob/yb/linux/test/test_gamepads.py).
They all pass on Windows, and fail on Linux.

(You can test on your system: clone the repo, checkout the `yb/linux` branch, follow the prerequisite instructions for Linux, install locally with `pip install -e .` and run the python script in the `test` directory)

On Linux, `pygame` correctly detects the `uinput` device with its expected characteristics, and thus the following tests are successful:

```py
# Check that only one gamepad is connected:
self.assertTrue(len(self.joysticks) == 1)
j = self.joysticks[0]

# Check that gamepad properties are correct:
name = j.get_name()
nb_axes = j.get_numaxes()
nb_balls = j.get_numballs()
nb_buttons = j.get_numbuttons()
nb_hats = j.get_numhats()
self.assertTrue(name == "Xbox 360 Controller")
self.assertEqual(nb_axes, 6)
self.assertEqual(nb_balls, 0)
self.assertEqual(nb_buttons, 11)
self.assertEqual(nb_hats, 1)
```

However, further events are not correctly detected, and thus [this test](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad/blob/97f7d17d628558e996e63ac2f5e7aef3c456bcc4/test/test_gamepads.py#L85) fails:

```py
_ = pygame.event.get()

self.g.press_button(button=v_button)
self.g.update()
time.sleep(WAIT_S)

event = pygame.event.get()
print(event)
self.assertTrue(j.get_button(j_button))
```

At this point, the `A` button is supposed to be detected as pressed, and in fact the [gamepad tester website](https://hardwaretester.com/gamepad) does correctly show button `A` as pressed.
Yet, `pygame` does not see the event and the `print` that I have added here prints `[]`.

Finally, I have manually tried a modded version of the same code using a real gamepad, and this time the test passed correctly.

Does anyone know why this might happen, please?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I have also tried creating a display with `pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))` and focusing the created window before sending the `uinput` events, but got the same behavior: no `uinput` events were detected by `pygame`, only the mouse events corresponding to me focusing the window.

Answer (score 1):

The [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module an [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) requires an initialized display on the same device in the same thread:

> Pygame handles all its event messaging through an event queue. The routines in this module help you manage that event queue. The input queue is heavily dependent on the `pygame.display` module. **If the display has not been initialized and a video mode not set, the event queue may not work properly.**

[`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) / [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)

> Caution: This function should only be called in the thread that initialized `pygame.display`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but `pygame.init()` is called in the setUp function, and adding pygame.display.init() there does not change anything. Also, the same code works when using a real gamepad instead of uinput.

Comment: @YannBouteiller  `pygame.init` is not what you need. You need an initalized `pygame.display`. So you have to create a display with [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). Likely `uinput` sends the events through the display's event loop. You're relying on undefined behavior, so don't be surprised if it doesn't work.

Comment: I have also tested creating a display with `set_mode()`, the behavior is the same except it creates a black window (that I have also tried focusing with the mouse before sending the `uinput` events: when I focus I get the mouse events, but still no events from `uinput`)